# Gson is not setting model class

Tags: android, gson

I am using **gson** to set my model class.

Dependency used - compile '**com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0**'

My Model class:

```
public class DemoBean {

    private String curr_avl_bal;
    private String loan_acc_no;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String hasSubCode;

    public String getCurr_avl_bal() {
        return curr_avl_bal;
    }

    public void setCurr_avl_bal(String curr_avl_bal) {
        this.curr_avl_bal = curr_avl_bal;
    }

    public String getLoan_acc_no() {
        return loan_acc_no;
    }

    public void setLoan_acc_no(String loan_acc_no) {
        this.loan_acc_no = loan_acc_no;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHasSubCode() {
        return hasSubCode;
    }

    public void setHasSubCode(String hasSubCode) {
        this.hasSubCode = hasSubCode;
    }
}
```

In my Activity:

```
GsonBuilder mBuilder = new GsonBuilder(); 
Gson mGson = mBuilder.create(); 
DemoBean demoBean = mGson.fromJson(res,DemoBean.class);
```

But demoBean is null. Why this happens?

Comment: Please post your res data which you passing in argument.

Comment: @Dhaval {
  "curr_avl_bal": "562",
  "loan_acc_no": "841152",
  "name": "demo",
  "id": "545",
  "hasSubCode": "Y"
}

Answer (score 0):

```
 YourObject parsed = new Gson().fromJson(jsons, YourObject.class);
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

I tested its working fine in my demo below is the code which I am using

```
GsonBuilder mBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson mGson = mBuilder.create();
        String res = "{ \"curr_avl_bal\": \"562\", \"loan_acc_no\": \"841152\", \"name\": \"demo\", \"id\": \"545\", \"hasSubCode\": \"Y\" } ";
        DemoBean demoBean = mGson.fromJson(res, DemoBean.class);
        Logger.print("This demo bean" + demoBean.getCurr_avl_bal());
```